# Browsersync Laravel mix, Error: watch ENOSPC throw er; Unhandled 'error' event

Tags: webpack, browser-sync, laravel-mix

When I am running `npm run watch-poll` in Laravel mix with the feature browsersync:

```
mix.browserSync('https://vuravel.local')
```

I am getting this weird error. I have no idea how to solve this. Any ideas?

I am running an apache server on Ubuntu with Google Chrome as a browser.

```
[Browsersync] Access URLs:
 ---------------------------------------
 Local: https://localhost:3000
 External: https://192.168.1.244:3000
 ---------------------------------------
 UI: http://localhost:3001
 UI External: http://localhost:3001
 ---------------------------------------
 [Browsersync] Watching files...
events.js:183
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

 Error: watch /path/to/root/***.php ENOSPC
at _errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
at FSWatcher.start (fs.js:1382:19)
at Object.fs.watch (fs.js:1408:11)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

ENOSPC is a "no space available error".

What you have to do is increase the max amount of files you can watch by running this command in your terminal:

```
echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p
```